# Easiest way to persist Cassandra data to S3 using Spark

Tags: amazon-s3, cassandra, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to figure out how to best store and retrieve data, from S3 to Cassandra, using Spark: I have log data that I store in Cassandra. I run Spark using DSE to perform analysis of the data, and it works beautifully. The log data grows daily, and I only need two weeks worth in Cassandra at any given time. I still need to store older logs somewhere for at least 6 months, and after research, S3 with Glaciar looks like the most promising solution. I'd like to use Spark, to run a daily job that finds the logs from day 15, deletes them from Cassandra, and sends them to S3. My problem is this: I can't seem to settle on the right format to save the Cassandra rows to a file, such that I can one day potentially load the file back into Spark, and run an analysis, if I have to. I only want to run the analysis in Spark one day, not persist the data back into Cassandra. JSON seems to be an obvious solution, but is there any other format that I am not considering? Should I use Spark SQL? Any advice appreciated before I commit to one format or another.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Spark](https://parquet.apache.org/) is designed for this kind of use case. It is a storage format for columnar databases. It provides column compression and some indexing.

It is becoming a de facto standard. Many big data platforms are adopting it or at least providing some support for it. 
You can query it efficiently directly in S3 using SparkSQL, Impala or Apache Drill. You can also run EMR jobs against it.

To write data to Parquet using Spark, use `DataFrame.saveAsParquetFile`.

Depending on your specific requirements you may even end up not needing a separate Cassandra instance.

You may also find [this post](http://svds.com/post/flexible-data-architecture-spark-cassandra-and-impala) interesting

Comment: Soon after I asked this question, I noticed that SparkSQL has a toJSON method on the SchemaRDD object. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: That is certainly an option, but I thought you still also wanted to be able to query the data efficiently. You can run spark and EMR jobs against JSON in S3, but that requires a lot more network bandwidth and you have to scand and sparse all the data for each query.

Comment: Ah, I do want to query the data, but at some semi-distant point in the future. I can persist the data to s3, and then read it back in JSON form into Spark. Thank you for your help.